# Date format conversion c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Guys I have a string having a date in the format dd/mm/YYYY.

However I need to use it a datetimepicker control.

I cannot assign the value to the datetimepicker, i tried as

```
string exp = "SELECT UserPwdExpiry FROM " + MainForm.schema + "Adm.SysUser WHERE USerId ='" + cmbUserID.Text + "'";

cmd = ccs.CreateCommand();
ccs.Open();
cmd.CommandText = exp;
DateTime expiry_ = ((DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
//string _expiry_= expiry_.ToShortDateString(); 
ccs.Close();
```

assigning here

```
dtpPasswordExpiry.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_expiry_);
```

It gives me an error saying, FORMAT SHOW BE BETWEEN MaxDate and MinDate.

Help please.

Comment: have you set any max and min date for the date picker ?

Comment: You should use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and you don't need to convert the datetime to string to remove the time part. You just need to use it's `Date` property: `dtpPasswordExpiry.Value = User_modify.Date`

Comment: Where is the value for `_expiry_` coming from???

Comment: Does your datepicker control expect the same format as your date values? If for any reason day and month are mixed your datepicker would get a month with a value above 12 and throw an error like you experience

Comment: SQL INJECTION! please, please, please make the userid a parameter - `... WHERE USerId = @userId` and add it in: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userId", cmbUserID.Text)`. This will save you a lot of problems - like having your database deleted.

Answer (score 0):

if `DateTime expiry_ = ((DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar());` this line running without errors you already have Datetime object. So you can directly set it as

```
tpPasswordExpiry.Value =expiry_;
```

But above line will fail if you store datetime as string in database then

```
string _User_modify= (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(_User_modify, 
                       "dd/MM/YYYY", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt))
{
    tpPasswordExpiry.Value =dt;
}
```

Comment: But he could successfully cast the value to `DateTime`, so obviously it is datetime in database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Still notworking when i added .Date. It says ---Value of '3/22/2013 12:00:00 AM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value !!

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn have you change MinDate and MaxDate of your `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: @Damith Yes I have checked. It is in required range. Still same error being given.

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn what is the `CustomFormat` you given for `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: @Damith ... its none, Does this has anythng to do with the error according to you ?

Answer (score 0):

We already have:

```
DateTime expiry = ((DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

so: we know the value is a `DateTime`. The `DateTimePicker` control's `.Value` property *is* a `DateTime`, so the correct syntax here is:

```
dtpPasswordExpiry.Value = expiry;
```

The only thing that leaves, based on the error message, is the [`MinDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [`MaxDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx). I suspect you need to change the values of those two properties such that your `expiry` is a legal value not outside the range `MinDate` - `MaxDate`. If unsure, simply print out the values of `expiry`, `dtpPasswordExpiry.MinDate` and `dtpPasswordExpiry.MaxDate`.